# How to keep track of event subscriptions for various events

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling, eventhandler

Consider the example bellow. This example has a simple event source (Ticker) and a form that subscribes to its event (Ticked) via a delegate that updates the form title. This example has only one event for simplicity, but consider the case where there are a multitude of events to which multiple forms subscribe.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        // event cannot be used as a key type
        // Dictionary<event, List<EventHandler>> subscriptions = new Dictionary<event, List<EventHandler>>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Ticker ticker = new Ticker();
            Form form = new Form();
            form.Show();
            EventHandler eventHandler = new EventHandler((s, e) => {
                form.Invoke(new Action(() => { form.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); }));
            });
            // save a reference to the event and the delegate to be added
            //if (!subscriptions.ContainsKey(ticker.Ticked))
            //    subscriptions.Add(ticker.Ticked, new List<EventHandler>());
            //subscriptions[ticker.Ticked].Add(eventHandler);
            //form.FormClosing += (s, e) => {
            //    foreach (KeyValuePair<event, List<EventHandler>> subscription in subscriptions)
            //        foreach (EventHandler eventHandler in subscription.Value)
            //            subscription.Key -= eventHandler;
            //};
            //finally subscribe to the event(s)
            ticker.Ticked += eventHandler;
            Application.Run();
        }

        class Ticker
        {
            public event EventHandler Ticked;

            public Ticker()
            {
                new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Ticked?.Invoke(null, null);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                })).Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can you save in a collection the events the form subscribed and the delegates added to each event by the form, so that they can be removed before closing the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: this is impossible. You can't store events in collections and clear their handler lists later.

Events serve only one purpose - encapsulation. The only thing they do is provide accessors (namely `add` and `remove`) so code outside your class can only add/remove handlers to a backing delegate field. These pieces of code are basically same:

```
class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;
}
```

```
class MyClass
{
    private EventHandler myDelegate;

    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add => myDelegate += value;
        remove => myDelegate -= value;
    }
}
```

But suppose we don't use events, and use delegates directly. You could create a dictionary where the keys are delegates instead of events, but that wouldn't work for your problem. This is because **delegates are immutable**. You can't store a delegate in a collection and then retrieve it and clear its invokation list.

The only solution here would be to reference every event directly, like in this code. I'm not sure whether this solution will work for you.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var ticker = new Ticker();
            var form = new Form();
            form.Show();

            form.FormClosing += (s, e) => ticker.ClearSubscriptions();

            ticker.Ticked += new EventHandler((s, e) => form.Invoke(
                new Action(() => form.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString())));

            Application.Run();
        }

        class Ticker
        {
            public event EventHandler Ticked;

            public Ticker()
            {
                new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Ticked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                })).Start();
            }

            public void ClearSubscriptions()
            {
                Ticked = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, `ClearSubscriptions` clears the `Ticked` event manually. If you have more events, you must also clear them manually and only in the `Ticker` class, because it's the only place that has access to the underlying delegate. You can only clear the events you've declared yourself.

Alternatively, you could store a separate list for each event.

```
static void Main()
{
    var ticker = new Ticker();
    var form = new Form();
    form.Show();

    var tickedSubscriptions = new List<EventHandler>();

    form.FormClosing += (s, e) =>
    {
        foreach (var subscription in tickedSubscriptions)
        {
            ticker.Ticked -= subscription;
        }

        tickedSubscriptions.Clear();
    };

    var handler = new EventHandler((s, e) => form.Invoke(
        new Action(() => form.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString())));

    tickedSubscriptions.Add(handler);
    ticker.Ticked += handler;

    Application.Run();
}
```

But in my opinion, this solution is less than ideal, because you have to keep track of many separate lists.

**UPDATE:**

I've thought of another solution which works for your case. I'm not sure whether it's elegant though.

Even though delegates are immutable, nothing prevents us from creating wrapper objects that can change the backing delegate and put these wrappers into the dictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Dictionary<EventHandlerWrapper, List<EventHandler>> subscriptions =
        new Dictionary<EventHandlerWrapper, List<EventHandler>>();

        static void Main()
        {
            var ticker = new Ticker();
            var form = new Form();
            form.Show();

            form.FormClosing += (s, e) =>
            {
                foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
                {
                    foreach (var handler in subscription.Value)
                    {
                        subscription.Key.Remove(handler);
                    }
                }

                subscriptions.Clear();
            };

            var updateTitle = new EventHandler((s, e) =>
                form.Invoke(new Action(() => form.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString())));

            ticker.Ticked += updateTitle;
            subscriptions.Add(ticker.TickedWrapper, new List<EventHandler> { updateTitle });

            Application.Run();
        }

        class Ticker
        {
            public event EventHandler Ticked;
            public EventHandlerWrapper TickedWrapper;

            public Ticker()
            {
                TickedWrapper = new EventHandlerWrapper(
                    () => Ticked,
                    handler => Ticked += handler,
                    handler => Ticked -= handler);

                new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Ticked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                })).Start();
            }
        }

        class EventHandlerWrapper
        {
            public Func<EventHandler> Get { get; }
            public Action<EventHandler> Add { get; }
            public Action<EventHandler> Remove { get; }

            public EventHandlerWrapper(
                Func<EventHandler> get,
                Action<EventHandler> add,
                Action<EventHandler> remove)
            {
                this.Get = get;
                this.Add = add;
                this.Remove = remove;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution will not work because `ClearSubscriptions()` will clear all subscriptions, instead of only the ones added by `form`. The second solution is what  I'm currently doing. I keep a list for each event at each consumer, hence I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Chris There is a solution which can work for you - I've updated my answer.